# Bluemix - Some bugs about virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

<[Bugpicture_1_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k91l.png)丨[Bugpicture_1_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLSpf.png)>

As you can see.I have two instances in total,but I only can control one of them.

I can't see the other one on Bluemix console either.

**I wonder to know how to delete that one.**

I can't terminate the instances in the secound picutre.
I had tried many times to do that.
After wating,nothing happened.And its status is error.

I don't know what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the
  upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support
  widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of
  assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.